# Without hardcore value in CASE (SQL or knex )

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count

i had done for my logic, but it is a hardcore value for **Classiky** and **Stationery**, is any way i able to do after filtering.

```
SELECT 
    b.name AS brand_name,
    c.name AS category_name,
    sum(case when b.name = 'Classiky' then 1 else 0 end) AS brandCount,
    sum(case when c.name = 'Stationery' then 1 else 0 end) AS categoryCount
FROM products  p
JOIN categories_products__products_categories  cp
    ON cp.product_id = p.id
JOIN categories c
    ON category_id = c.id 
LEFT JOIN brands b
    ON brand = b.id
WHERE category_slug = "queryFromURL"
GROUP BY brand_name, category_name
```

Above SQL Statement output:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|  brand_name | category_name | brandCount | categoryCount |
+-------------+---------------+------------+---------------+
|  Classiky   |    Tapes      |     2      |       0       |
|   SARASA    |   Stationery  |     0      |       2       |
|   Paper     |    Notes      |     0      |       0       |
+-------------+---------------+------------+---------------+
```

Since i am hardcore value for it, so the result will look like above table.

As example: i have data of brand and category in category after filtering

1. Classiky   (brand)
2. SARASA     (brand)
3. Paper      (brand)
4. Tapes      (category)
5. Stationery (category)
6. Notes (category)

i wanna to count how many i have after filtering in brandCount, same as categoryCount instead of hardcore the value for it.

what i expected output: (eg: there has "Tapes category" for 3 after filtered)

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|  brand_name | category_name | brandCount | categoryCount |
+-------------+---------------+------------+---------------+
|  Classiky   |    Tapes      |     2      |       3       |
|   SARASA    |   Stationery  |     4      |       2       |
|   Paper     |    Notes      |     6      |       4       |
+-------------+---------------+------------+---------------+
```

I using **knex** for this sql. But it is more understanding for us, so i write in raw sql. Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Without sample data, it is really hard to follow your issue.  If you set up a db/sql fiddle of some sort, your question might be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
count(b.id) AS brandCount,
count(distinct c.id) AS categoryCount
```

Comment: yes. Really appreciate for your help. it work and surprise me, it is only two line of code.